# Object received as null when dispatched through an event

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, null, garbage-collection

I have a fairly basic Logger

```
public class Logger: ILogger
{
  public event EventHandler<MessageLoggedArgs> MessageLogged;
  ...
  public void LogMessage(string msg, LogType logType)
  {
    var logItem = new LogItem(msg, logType);
    addLogMessage(logItem);
  }

  private void addLogMessage(LogItem logItem)
  {
    MessageLogged?.Invoke(this, new MessageLoggedArgs(logItem));
  }
}

public class MessageLoggedArgs
{ 
   public LogItem LogItem {get;}
   public MessageLoggedArgs(LogItem logitem)
   {
       LogItem = logItem;
   }
}

public class LogsProcessor
{ 
    public LogsProcessor(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.MessageLogged += OnMessageLogged;

    }

    private volatile List<LogItem> buffer = new List<LogItem>();

    private ManualResetEvent ev = new ManualResetEvent(true);

    private void OnMessageLogged(object sender, MessageLoggerArgs e)
    {
        buffer.Add(e.LogItem);
        ev.Set();
    }

    //Runs on a thread
    private void process()
    {
       while(true)
       {
          ev.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);

          if(buffer.Count != 0)
          {
              while(buffer.Count != 0)
              {
                  var item = logbuffer[0];
                  buffer.RemoveAt(0);
                  Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
                                 ( new Action( () => { //Log to UI }));
              }

          }
          else
             ev.Reset();
       }
    }
}
```

The consumer of this class receives some null objects when a lot of logs are generated. Is it possible that the objects are being garbage collected? If yes, then how is it possible that the logs are garbage collected, even though there is always a reference to the object alive inside of the MessageLoggedAgs. 
This has me baffled.

Edit: Turns out that the problem is somehow because of accessing the buffer using a thread. I was able to eliminate the issue by using a ConcurrentQueue. However, I don't know where exactly the issue was earlier. I thought it wouldn't be an issue if I was accessing buffer using a single thread.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by 'null entries' ? I don't think that we will be able to help without getting the big picture though.

Comment: "_Is it possible that the objects are being garbage collected?_" No. As you already said, as long as something somewhere holds a reference to an object, that object will not be GCed. Although, if WeakReferences are used by your program, that would be an entirely different ball game...

Comment: I have made some edits. Hopefully, that provides enough context. No, I am not using any weak references.

Comment: Throw a breakpoint on `OnMessageLogged`.  Check that the `sender` is what you expect and that events are not being raised by another source.  If so, check the call stack to see where they are coming from.

Comment: @MrZander - You may be right. These nulls are probably being generated from elsewhere.

Comment: Ok. So, I think the issue is because I am removing the logs from a thread. There is a race condition somewhere.